# How to make the mapView transparent in Android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, transparent

I want to make a mapview totally transparent without making my overlays that are drawn on top transparent. I have already read these posts: [How to make MapView object transparent (alpha)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979405/how-to-make-mapview-object-transparent-alpha) and: http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/15/tutorial-1-transparent-panel-linear-layout-on-mapview-google-map/. Unfortunately they didn't solve my problem.

Here is a more detailed explanation of the problem: I have subclassed the MapView class (com.google.android.maps.MapView) and drawn its canvas with a call to super.dispatchDraw(Canvas c) before drawing my overlays within the MapView's dispatchDraw-method. I have also succeeded in adding a transparent color on top of the mapView and my overlays are successfully drawn on top of this color. However I can't find a way of making the MapView's canvas transparent so that I can show my overlays (without any visual mapview info) on top of an underlying imageView. Anyone have a solution? Been struggling with this for a long while now!

Comment: You may wonder why I don't use a RelativeLayout and do the overlaying myself?! The reason is that my overlays represent objects placed on an actual map (the distance between them etc). So I want to make use of the map system but I don't want the MapView's visual information...

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution for your question ? because, now I'm on same situation buddy.. can you help me please