# How to make MapView transparent on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, view, android-mapview, transparent

I'm working on a mapping app. And I want to show some views under the MapView. I'm using the method:

```
mapView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Nothing happens to the mapView. When I try to apply this method to my buttons it works fine, even applying it to the parent view of the mapView makes every child view transparent except for the mapView.

When I don't initialize the mapView it shows as blank and fully transparent, so I know that it has something to do with the mapView rendering the tiles fully opaque.

I have used a custom mapView class and overridden the dispatchDraw and did some canvas editing there but no results.

How can we make the mapView transparent? I have looked into other questions here and I cant seem to find a solution.

Is there some special method in the mapView.getMap() that we can use to make it transparent?

I know this is a bad design choice (putting a view under the map), but I wanna know any solution to this.

Comment: what type of UI or screen you want exactly ,?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979405/how-to-make-mapview-object-transparent-alpha

Comment: @Viren The answer in that post only makes a transparent layer above the map.

Comment: Maybe it's hard to make the Map to be a transparent. You can try to make the view of which you want to show as transparent overlay on the google map itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised a bug report with android about not being able to set the base map tiles to be transparent - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114859230

Please star it so they pay attention.